# Why not Indian fisherman? Article headline: "India fisherman killed as Pakistan navy opens fire"

Tags: word-choice, headlinese

I read an [article](http://www.firstpost.com/world/pakistan-navy-shoots-at-2-indian-boats-with-5-fishermen-onboard-kills-1-2438732.html) which has a title *(but it's now changed)*:

> ***India*** fisherman killed as Pakistan navy opens fire at two boats off Gujarat Coast

My questions are: Which word is correct in this context, 'India' or 'Indian'? Why?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: I'd **certainly** use the adjective.

Comment: Looking at the article now, it says "Indian" in the headline.

Comment: @MasonWheeler An ELL's impact! :)

Comment: Now that's called an ELL effect! But those guys keep on changing the headlines, not fair! https://web.archive.org/web/20150918104410/http://www.firstpost.com/world/pakistan-navy-shoots-at-2-indian-boats-with-5-fishermen-onboard-kills-1-2438732.html

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The title is written in **[headlinese](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Headlinese)**, a specific style for newspaper headlines. Headline writers often pick a noun where an adjective would've been more logical (in a general-purpose text).

As the [article in WIkipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Headlinese) states, "*Country names are often used instead of their adjective form.*"

Comment: This is the first time I encountered the term **headlinese**. Thanks for the info!

Comment: @shin - you're welcome! "StackExchange user encounters headlinese, impressed". (0:

Comment: Indian media can prove this incorrect! You may find them using ['adjective' in the headline and 'noun' in the body](http://zeenews.india.com/news/india/in-touch-with-sri-lanka-regarding-death-penalty-to-five-indian-fishermen-mea_1491689.html)! *(pun intended!)*

Comment: @MaulikV Good find! Indeed, the authors used headlinese where they should've journalese. (0:

Comment: Since the headline *now* reads "Indian fisherman ..." it would appear that it was written in **typo**ese.

Comment: Yeah, as a native speaker, "India fisherman killed..." just looks incorrect, no matter what the style may be.

Comment: I've always thought one of the reasons they do this is because the shorter the word, the larger the typeface they can use.

Comment: @PeterG: That, and using the adjective descriptor for a citizen of a foreign country might be more confusing than just using the country name. Some nationalities use adjectives that are substantially different from the country name. If the writer uses a country name, he can be sure that the readers will know which country the person is from.

Answer (score 3):

I agree with CopperKettle's answer, and wanted to provide some more information. English language newspaper articles are a unique genre of English language writing, whose style is generally dictated by the [Associated Press Stylebook](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AP_Stylebook). This guide not only defines headlines, but also what words are appropriate for use, how sources should be cited, and much more.

Comment: and to add more information - for some nations - if you were to try and describe the person's nationality via ethnicity you might end up either offending (*some*) people from that country, or being too specific and your readers don't know what you're talking about. It's easier just to list the country.

Comment: "[The style of] English language newspaper articles [...] is generally dictated by the Associated Press Stylebook." Is that true, outside the US? Also, by "dictated", I think you mean "informed".

Comment: Dictated is reasonable when talking about style manuals, because generally organizations involved in publishing will adopt a style manual and instruct their writers to follow it. The style manual does dictate, because you must follow the rules or face criticism or even disciplinary action.